# What happens to application's process after ANR Application Not Responding

Tags: android

**What happens to application's process after ANR Application Not Responding?**

The application process is destroyed and then popup is shown? Or process is killed after user presses OK on that popup? Or process is not killed when ANR is caused by Activity and there's a Service running also in that process? Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: IMO, your process will get killed when the user seleck "OK". http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

Comment: An ANR warning appears when the main (UI) thread has been detected as not responding for an unacceptable length of time. At the point the popup appears, the whole of the app process is still loaded and running (albeit in a long sequence of operations or an infinite loop etc) - it is not destroyed immediately. If the user selects "Wait" then the OS does exactly that and if the ANR is simply caused by a long running task, it's possible for the app to continue (eventually) as expected. If the user selects to terminate the app however, the entire app is forcibly terminated and unloaded.

Comment: Please be precise - what do you mean "terminated" and "unloaded" - what about application process? I've edited my question as I'm interested in "What happens to application process".

Comment: @MarianPaździoch : Everything. As I said, the *entire* app. A standard Android app runs on a single thread in a single process. Everything is basically killed and the DVM hosting the process is also destroyed.